# User info command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord

Hi so I'm learning by myself to code a discord bot in JavaScript but I have this error and I don't understand if I missed something
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined`
And here is what I did :

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

  const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
  const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
  
  let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setAuthor(user.tag)
  .setDescription("Users Info", true)
  .setColor("#64FF00", true)
  .addField("Full Username:", user.tag , true)
  .addField("ID:", user.id, true)
  .addField("Created at:", user.createdAt, true)
  .addField("Status:", user.presence.status , true)
  .addField("Game:", user.presence.game ? user.presence.game : 'none' , true)
  .addField("Roles", member.roles.map(r => `${r}`).join(' | '), true);
message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

**EDIT**:
I figured out my code was outdated xD

Answer (score 0):

The error itself provides the answer. It says `TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined` that means there is a property of which you want to read users from in your case its `message.mentions.users`. In this it says that mentions is undefined. This could mean that there was some other error or that it was never mentioned.
You can use `message.mentions?.users` if in angular it says if mentions is undefined then return undefined do not check its users value.